# how to get property create in derived class using a pointer to based class c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

look at following code:

```
class A
{
 public:
    virtual int getN();// have to write it's body, but how?
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    int n = 2;
public:
    int getN() { return n; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A *p = &b;
    p->getN();
}
```

usually `virtual` function is a good solution. However when the based class does not own the new property created by derived class, how to access the new property from a pointer to based class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pure virtual function declaration in the base and then you don't have to provide a body for the function, though you still can.

```
virtual int getN() = 0;
```

"Get" functions, if they exist at all, should usually be const:

```
virtual int getN() const = 0;
```

If you do this you'll not be able to directly instantiate the base class.  You can have pointers and references of that type, but never objects.